# Dependency Injection - Eclipse e4 app to eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp

I've a e4 application which calls a plugin project via a handler.

```
public class CTGHandler{
    @Execute
    public void execute(final EPartService partService, final EModelService modelService){
        MPart mPart = modelService.createModelElement(MPart.class);
        mPart.setLabel("CTG"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        mPart.setContributionURI("bundleclass://plugin.project.ctg/test.project.ctg.CTG"); 
        partService.showPart(mPart, PartState.ACTIVATE);

    }

}
```

On the plugin side

```
public class CTG{

    private final Composite parent;
    private Scale scale;

    @Inject
    public CTG(Composite parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void create(){
        scale = new Scale();
        Axis x = new Axis(scale);
        ....
    }
}
```

and the Scale class looks as follows

```
public class Scale{

    private int x;

    @Inject
    public Scale(){
        x = 10;
    }
}
```

Issue: I'm passing `scale` as a parameter to the Axis class `Axis x = new Axis(scale);`

Question: How can I use dependency injection on the scale object so that its available for the Axis class or any other class in the plugin project without passing it as a variable to the constructor. I tried adding `@Inject private Scale scale` in CTG.java and Axis.java but Axis class doesn't get a value of scale.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `@Creatable` annotation to the `Scale` class to tell the injector to create a new instance when it is needed:

```
@Creatable
public class Scale
{
  ...
}
```

If you only want a single instance of `Scale` add `@Singleton`:

```
@Creatable
@Singleton
public class Scale
{
  ...
}
```

You can also use an OSGi service to create singleton classes, or inject then in to the context in an AddOn or LifeCycle class.

Dependency injection is normally only done on objects created by Eclipse. If you want to do injection on objects you create you use `ContextInjectionFactory` to create the object:

```
@Inject
IEclipseContext context;

...

Axis x = ContextInjectionFactory.make(Axis.class, context);
```

An alternate version of `make` lets you add extra values:

```
IEclipseContext staticContext = EclipseContextFactory.create();

staticContext.set(Scale.class, scale);

Axis x = ContextInjectionFactory.make(Axis.class, context, staticContext);
```